# Read unsaved buffer, is it possible?

Tags: vimscript

I see a lot of interesting features released with vim 8. Is there a chance read unsaved buffer with timers or when i type something without writing buffer to the file and without shortcuts just with timers or, maybe async task ? I have to say that i'm new to vim..vimscript.

Comment: you should be more precise what exactly you need.

Comment: how can i read current buffer without saving it ? idk how it can be more clear

Comment: Read to what? Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: `getline(1, '$')` ?

Comment: @TommyA , you are my hero

Answer (score 2):

`getline(1, '$')` seems to work just fine with timers . Thanks to [@Tommy A](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/5229/tommy-a).

Comment: No problem. Take a look at `:h text-functions` if you're working on productivity scripts.